# JMeter - How to use specific data from log file and pass as an input to another request

Tags: jmeter

I am using JDBC Request and passing a query which is returning the column value as CLOB
[ResponseDataOfJDBCRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptm43.png)

I had used below query in JSR223 PostProcessor to print the CLOB Value to JMeter Log file.

def data = vars.getObject('clob').get(2).get('ColumnName')?.characterStream?.text
log.info('Value from CLOB field: ' + data)

Which is printing the CLOB value to log file.
Now my question is how can I use the specific value from CLOB Field from the log file and pass it as an input in another request.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need to take the value from log if you have it as `data` variable?

- If you would like to extract the value in groovy - take a look at [Find operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator)
- You can add one more line to your groovy script:

  ```
  vars.put('data', data)
  ```

  and then

  - If you want the full text you can use `${data}` in the next request.
  - If you need partial data - you can use other JMeter's Post-Processors like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) to fetch the "interesting" part from the variable:

  [image]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T. The mentioned solution worked for me and can get my value from the data variable using Regular Expression Extractor.